# Error while converting a list to dict "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value"

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, key-value

```
import json

string = "'massage':'testing'"

json.loads(string)
```

But I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: it should be match the [json format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Syntax), you miss the brackets

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid JSON. This works:

```py
import json
string = '{"message": "testing"}'
print(json.loads(string))
```

Not sure what this has to do with converting lists to dictionaries though.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

> If the data being deserialized is not a valid JSON document, a
> JSONDecodeError will be raised.

you have 2 mistake

1. you miss the brackets in your string
2. [JSON specification - RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7) states that a string begins and ends with quotation mark.
   That mean single quoute `'` has no semantic meaning in JSON and is allowed only inside a string.

result:

```py
import json
string = '{"massage":"testing"}'
json.loads(string)
```